Why does Blender Crash everytime I open the shader tab?
I have issues with the latest Blender Version(4.2). Everytime I try to open Material Preview Mode, Render Prieview, the Shading tab or even just a material preview in the properties tab, Blender Crashes(without freezing first).
One crash text/log:
# Blender 4.2.0, Commit date: 2024-07-16 06:20, Hash a51f293548ad

# backtrace
Exception Record:

ExceptionCode         : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Exception Address     : 0x00007FF61E845074
Exception Module      : blender.exe
Exception Flags       : 0x00000000
Exception Parameters  : 0x2
    Parameters[0] : 0x0000000000000000
    Parameters[1] : 0x0000000000000008


Stack trace:
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61E845070  GPU_shader_get_ssbo_binding
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C946510  blender::eevee::LightModule::culling_pass_sync
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C946FF0  blender::eevee::LightModule::end_sync
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C959C20  blender::eevee::Instance::render_sync
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C959AE0  blender::eevee::Instance::render_sample
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C9596D0  blender::eevee::Instance::render_frame
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C915910  eevee_render_to_image
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C8C86A0  DRW_render_to_image
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61D3C4D90  engine_render_view_layer
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61D3C64D0  RE_engine_render
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61D3CD9F0  RE_PreviewRender
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61D22FBA0  shader_preview_render
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61D22FDD0  shader_preview_startjob
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7B1C20  do_job_thread
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7DE830  _ptw32_threadStart
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Threads:
Thread : 00003d20
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C4830  ZwWaitForMultipleObjects
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669AD8E0  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669AD8C0  WaitForMultipleObjects
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7DCA40  _ptw32_callUserDestroyRoutines
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7E16F0  sem_timedwait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7DCA40  _ptw32_callUserDestroyRoutines
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C6B4EF0  BLI_ticket_mutex_lock
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C8C7580  DRW_gpu_context_enable
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61E853C40  GPU_viewport_bind
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7C4930  wm_draw_window_offscreen
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7C4760  wm_draw_window
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7C4190  wm_draw_update
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C796360  ghost_event_proc
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61D9D59B0  GHOST_EventManager::dispatchEvents
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61D981960  GHOST_System::dispatchEvents
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C7978E0  wm_window_events_process
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C78BDB0  WM_main
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61C148160  main
blender.exe         :0x00007FF61EB52FD4  __scrt_common_main_seh
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00001f84
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C78B0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69436730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00003378
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C78B0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69436730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00003f1c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C78B0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69436730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000028d0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C3D60  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669A0E10  WaitForSingleObjectEx
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF49C0  IlmThread_3_2::Semaphore::wait
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF37A0  IlmThread_3_2::ThreadPool::setThreadProvider
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF1290  IlmThread_3_2::supportsThreads
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00004670
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C3D60  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669A0E10  WaitForSingleObjectEx
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF49C0  IlmThread_3_2::Semaphore::wait
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF37A0  IlmThread_3_2::ThreadPool::setThreadProvider
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF1290  IlmThread_3_2::supportsThreads
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00001d58
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C3D60  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669A0E10  WaitForSingleObjectEx
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF49C0  IlmThread_3_2::Semaphore::wait
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF37A0  IlmThread_3_2::ThreadPool::setThreadProvider
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF1290  IlmThread_3_2::supportsThreads
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00000b3c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C3D60  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669A0E10  WaitForSingleObjectEx
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF49C0  IlmThread_3_2::Semaphore::wait
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF37A0  IlmThread_3_2::ThreadPool::setThreadProvider
IlmThread.dll       :0x00007FFD57EF1290  IlmThread_3_2::supportsThreads
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00003628
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C78B0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69436730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00002ab0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C4830  ZwWaitForMultipleObjects
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669AD8E0  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
combase.dll         :0x00007FFD690BE0C0  CoTaskMemRealloc
combase.dll         :0x00007FFD690BE0C0  CoTaskMemRealloc
combase.dll         :0x00007FFD690BE0C0  CoTaskMemRealloc
combase.dll         :0x00007FFD690BE0C0  CoTaskMemRealloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00002a84
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C78B0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69436730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000036dc
win32u.dll          :0x00007FFD668BABE0  NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
USER32.dll          :0x00007FFD67FDD250  MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
USER32.dll          :0x00007FFD67FDD1A0  MsgWaitForMultipleObjects
directmanipulation.dll:0x00007FFD53825663  Symbols not available


Thread : 00000a5c
win32u.dll          :0x00007FFD668BABE0  NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
USER32.dll          :0x00007FFD67FDD250  MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
shcore.dll          :0x00007FFD68F13070  SHTaskPoolQueueTask
shcore.dll          :0x00007FFD68F11C10  Ordinal120
shcore.dll          :0x00007FFD68F107F0  SHQueryValueExW
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00003374
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C7850  ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD6948AB20  RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669BDAE0  SleepConditionVariableSRW
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFD440F2820  std::_Winerror_message
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFD440F2BB0  Cnd_wait
OpenImageIO_Util.dll:0x00007FFD5851C790  OpenImageIO_v2_5::paropt::operator=
OpenImageIO_Util.dll:0x00007FFD5851A080  OpenImageIO_v2_5::Sysutil::usleep
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00003af8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C7850  ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD6948AB20  RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669BDAE0  SleepConditionVariableSRW
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFD440F2820  std::_Winerror_message
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFD440F2BB0  Cnd_wait
OpenImageIO_Util.dll:0x00007FFD5851C790  OpenImageIO_v2_5::paropt::operator=
OpenImageIO_Util.dll:0x00007FFD5851A080  OpenImageIO_v2_5::Sysutil::usleep
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00001b6c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C7850  ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD6948AB20  RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669BDAE0  SleepConditionVariableSRW
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFD440F2820  std::_Winerror_message
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFD440F2BB0  Cnd_wait
OpenImageIO_Util.dll:0x00007FFD5851C790  OpenImageIO_v2_5::paropt::operator=
OpenImageIO_Util.dll:0x00007FFD5851A080  OpenImageIO_v2_5::Sysutil::usleep
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000038ac
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C3D60  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669A0E10  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFD5B16D800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFD5B16D800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000012a0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C3D60  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669A0E10  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFD5B16D800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFD5B16D800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000010c8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C3D60  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669A0E10  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFD5B16D800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFD5B16D800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFD67176BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00001428
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD694C3D60  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFD669A0E10  WaitForSingleObjectEx
atio6axx.dll        :0x00007FFD10166C70  DrvPresentBuffers
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFD688853D0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFD69424830  RtlUserThreadStart


Loaded Modules :
0x00007FF61C0C0000 4.2.0.0              blender.exe C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\blender.pdb 
0x00007FFD69420000 10.0.22000.2538      ntdll.dll  
0x00007FFD68870000 10.0.22000.2538      KERNEL32.DLL  
0x00007FFD66950000 10.0.22000.2538      KERNELBASE.dll  
0x00007FFD67FC0000 10.0.22000.2360      USER32.dll  
0x00007FFD668B0000 10.0.22000.2538      win32u.dll  
0x00007FFD687B0000 10.0.22000.2360      GDI32.dll  
0x00007FFD66ED0000 10.0.22000.2360      gdi32full.dll  
0x00007FFD66FF0000 10.0.22000.1         msvcp_win.dll  
0x00007FFD67150000 10.0.22000.1         ucrtbase.dll  
0x00007FFD67ED0000 10.0.22000.2360      ADVAPI32.dll  
0x00007FFD67C70000 7.0.22000.1          msvcrt.dll  
0x00007FFD68930000 10.0.22000.2360      sechost.dll  
0x00007FFD67270000 10.0.22000.2538      RPCRT4.dll  
0x00007FFD673A0000 10.0.22000.2482      SHELL32.dll  
0x00007FFD67D30000 10.0.22000.2538      ole32.dll  
0x00007FFD68FF0000 10.0.22000.2360      combase.dll  
0x00007FFD689F0000 10.0.22000.1         SHLWAPI.dll  
0x00007FFD681E0000 10.0.22000.1         WS2_32.dll  
0x00007FFD68250000 10.0.22000.2176      OLEAUT32.dll  
0x00007FFD68F00000 10.0.22000.613       shcore.dll  
0x00007FFD67F80000 10.0.22000.1641      IMM32.dll  
0x00007FFD5E1B0000 10.0.22000.1         VERSION.dll  
0x00007FFD53220000 10.0.22000.1         dbghelp.dll  
0x00007FFD58930000                      tbbmalloc.dll  
0x00007FFD62420000                      blender_cpu_check.dll  
0x00007FFD5B160000                      tbb.dll  
0x00007FFD2E960000 4.3.2.0              embree4.dll  
0x00007FFD1A7E0000                      cycles_kernel_oneapi_aot.dll  
0x00007FFD305C0000                      OpenImageIO.dll  
0x00007FFD2D3B0000                      oslcomp.dll  
0x00007FFD441F0000 7.2.0.8              sycl7.dll  
0x00007FFD584B0000                      OpenImageIO_Util.dll  
0x00007FFD5AF00000                      oslquery.dll  
0x00007FFD27340000                      oslexec.dll  
0x00007FFD588B0000                      boost_python311-vc142-mt-x64-1_82.dll  
0x00007FFD33010000                      OpenColorIO_2_3.dll  
0x00007FFD35720000 2.28.2.0             SDL2.dll  
0x00007FFD68330000 10.0.22000.2124      SETUPAPI.dll  
0x00007FFD58480000 2.3.0.0              OpenImageDenoise.dll  
0x00007FFD58400000 1.38.8.0             MaterialXFormat.dll  
0x00007FFD17310000 60.31.102.0          avcodec-60.dll  
0x00007FFD33D70000 60.16.100.0          avformat-60.dll  
0x00007FFD57700000 1.38.8.0             MaterialXCore.dll  
0x00007FFD61CF0000 60.3.100.0           avdevice-60.dll  
0x00007FFD2C1D0000 58.29.100.0          avutil-58.dll  
0x00007FFD57400000 7.5.100.0            swscale-7.dll  
0x00007FFD34670000 1.2.2.0              sndfile.dll  
0x00007FFD32E80000 1.23.1.0             OpenAL32.dll  
0x00007FFD2BF00000                      OpenEXR.dll  
0x00007FFD57F00000                      Iex.dll  
0x00007FFD25BB0000 11.0.0.0             openvdb.dll  
0x00007FFD576A0000                      Imath.dll  
0x00007FFD44170000                      boost_locale-vc142-mt-x64-1_82.dll  
0x00007FFD3FA10000                      gmp-10.dll  
0x00007FFD640A0000 10.0.22000.2245      dxgi.dll  
0x00007FFD3B130000                      epoxy-0.dll  
0x00007FFD440E0000 14.29.30139.0        MSVCP140.dll  
0x00007FFD664C0000 10.0.22000.2124      CFGMGR32.dll  
0x00007FFD59180000 14.29.30139.0        VCRUNTIME140.dll  
0x00007FFD5B080000 14.29.30139.0        VCRUNTIME140_1.dll  
0x00007FFD585C0000 6.10.22000.120       COMCTL32.dll  
0x00007FFD642C0000 10.0.22000.41        dwmapi.dll  
0x00007FFD5AE30000                      tbbmalloc_proxy.dll  
0x00007FFD2B8B0000 3.11.7150.1013       python311.dll  
0x00007FFD588A0000                      libgmpxx.dll  
0x00007FFD152D0000                      usd_ms.dll  
0x00007FFD30380000                      OpenEXRCore.dll  
0x00007FFD2B190000 10.0.22000.832       dbgeng.dll  
0x00007FFD583E0000                      boost_thread-vc142-mt-x64-1_82.dll  
0x00007FFD5D950000 10.0.22000.1         WINMM.dll  
0x00007FFD58890000                      oslnoise.dll  
0x00007FFD53470000 10.0.22000.675       Secur32.dll  
0x00007FFD573E0000 10.0.22000.1880      AVICAP32.dll  
0x00007FFD66190000 10.0.22000.2176      bcrypt.dll  
0x00007FFD53560000 7.7.0.8              pi_win_proxy_loader.dll  
0x00007FFD52F00000 4.12.100.0           swresample-4.dll  
0x00007FFD2AE90000 10.0.22000.1042      OPENGL32.dll  
0x00007FFD12600000 2.3.0.0              OpenImageDenoise_core.dll  
0x00007FFD57EF0000                      IlmThread.dll  
0x00007FFD403F0000 1.38.8.0             MaterialXGenGlsl.dll  
0x00007FFD3AB50000 10.0.22000.832       dbgmodel.dll  
0x00007FFD62450000 10.0.22000.282       XmlLite.dll  
0x00007FFD3C430000 1.38.8.0             MaterialXGenMsl.dll  
0x00007FFD4B250000 10.0.22000.1880      MSVFW32.dll  
0x00007FFD35EC0000 10.0.22000.1042      GLU32.dll  
0x00007FFD3B0A0000 1.38.8.0             MaterialXRender.dll  
0x00007FFD65B70000 10.0.22000.2245      SSPICLI.DLL  
0x00007FFD35670000 1.38.8.0             MaterialXGenShader.dll  
0x00007FFD64060000 10.0.22000.653       dxcore.dll  
0x00007FFD658E0000 10.0.22000.71        kernel.appcore.dll  
0x00007FFD64940000 10.0.22000.2245      windows.storage.dll  
0x00007FFD647D0000 10.0.22000.2360      wintypes.dll  
0x00007FFD667E0000 10.0.22000.2124      profapi.dll  
0x00007FFD63F50000 10.0.22000.2416      uxtheme.dll  
0x00007FFD66CE0000 10.0.22000.1455      bcryptPrimitives.dll  
0x00007FFD65F70000 10.0.22000.1         CRYPTBASE.DLL  
0x00007FFD68B40000 2001.12.10941.16384  clbcatq.dll  
0x00007FFD5D500000 10.0.22000.1042      MMDevApi.dll  
0x00007FFD66480000 10.0.22000.2124      DEVOBJ.dll  
0x00007FFD57F50000 10.0.22000.708       AUDIOSES.DLL  
0x00007FFD66780000 10.0.22000.1         powrprof.dll  
0x00007FFD66760000 10.0.22000.1         UMPDC.dll  
0x00007FFD68C00000 10.0.22000.1641      MSCTF.dll  
0x00007FFD62BB0000 7.0.22000.37         PROPSYS.dll  
0x00007FFD615D0000 10.0.22000.653       directxdatabasehelper.dll  
0x00007FFD65900000 10.0.22000.1         ntmarta.dll  
0x00007FFD60BC0000 10.0.22000.2538      AppXDeploymentClient.dll  
0x00007FFD609A0000 11.0.22000.2538      urlmon.dll  
0x00007FFD60110000 11.0.22000.2538      iertutil.dll  
0x00007FFD600E0000 10.0.22000.2124      srvcli.dll  
0x00007FFD653F0000 10.0.22000.434       netutils.dll  
0x00007FFD3C4F0000 27.20.1034.6         atig6pxx.dll  
0x00007FFD0F910000 27.20.1034.6         atio6axx.dll  
0x00007FFD2D2A0000 10.0.22000.1         dxva2.dll  
0x00007FFD3B300000 27.20.1034.6         atig6txx.dll  
0x00007FFD250A0000 27.20.1034.6         atiadlxx.dll  
0x000001CC71A20000 10.0.22000.1         PSAPI.DLL  
0x00007FFD668E0000 10.0.22000.2482      WINTRUST.dll  
0x00007FFD66D60000 10.0.22000.2482      CRYPT32.dll  
0x00007FFD660A0000 10.0.22000.1219      MSASN1.dll  
0x00007FFD4AB70000 10.0.22000.1         dataexchange.dll  
0x00007FFD5EA30000 10.0.22000.2538      twinapi.appcore.dll  
0x00007FFD41E30000 10.0.22000.2360      textinputframework.dll  
0x00007FFD63950000 10.0.22000.1042      CoreMessaging.dll  
0x00007FFD603F0000 10.0.22000.132       CoreUIComponents.dll  
0x00007FFD40620000 10.0.22000.2245      explorerframe.dll  
0x00007FFD53810000 10.0.22000.1         directmanipulation.dll  
0x00007FFD61EF0000 10.0.22000.2538      policymanager.dll  
0x00007FFD61AD0000 10.0.22000.1         msvcp110_win.dll  
0x00007FFD687F0000 10.0.22000.1         coml2.dll  
0x00007FFD61CD0000 10.0.22000.1         LINKINFO.dll  
0x00007FFD455B0000 10.0.22000.2124      Windows.StateRepositoryPS.dll  
0x00007FFD575B0000 10.0.22000.2124      windows.staterepositoryclient.dll  
0x00007FFD578C0000 10.0.22000.1165      Windows.System.Launcher.dll  
0x00007FFD582F0000 10.0.22000.2124      windows.staterepositorycore.dll  
0x00007FFD63DA0000 10.0.22000.1880      apphelp.dll  
0x00007FFD3AAF0000 10.0.22000.2538      zipfldr.dll  
0x000001CC00210000 3.11.7150.1013       python3.DLL  
0x00007FFD42EC0000 3.11.7150.1013       _socket.pyd  
0x00007FFD65400000 10.0.22000.282       IPHLPAPI.DLL  
0x00007FFD57DF0000 3.11.7150.1013       select.pyd  

# Python backtrace

If this is a Problem with my Hardware, I have listed the Specifications below:
Processor:AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics,3.50 GHz
RAM:8,00 GB (6,93 GB usable)
Please Tell what Upgrades I would need to continue working.
Thank you for your Time

Got the same crash, using a Windows 10 over bootcamp. Downgrading to 4.1.1 solved the issue.
